# Javascript if else statement within a Function Expression

Tags: javascript

I am currently studying Javascript. I tried to download a sample codes where in, there will be a transition of images. Some of the functions have codes I can't fully understand.

the first function is:

```
function addElementEvent(o,e,f){
    var of = o[e];
    var f2 = function(){of();f();}
    o[e] = !is_function(of) ? f : f2;
}
```

I am wondering what is the value of f(). May you please help me>

and the second function is this:

```
var _loadImage = [];
function loadImage(s,f,always_show_loading){
    var i_onload = function(){_loadImage[s]=true;if(f)f(s);}
    var l = function(){if(_loadImage[s]){if(f)f(s);}else{var i=newElement('IMG');i.onload=i_onload;new function(){i.src=s;};}}
    if(always_show_loading) setTimeout(l, typeof(always_show_loading) == 'number' ? always_show_loading : 1000);
    else l();
}
```

then this is the LOC I can't fully understand in the second function.

var i_onload = function(){_loadImage[s]=true;if(f)f(s);}

Is that line a shortcut for an if,else statement?

May you please explain the meaning of this code?

Thank you!

Comment: `var i_onload = function(){_loadImage[s]=true;if(f)f(s);}`
Can be write : 
`var i_onload = function () {
 _loadImages[s] = true;
if (f) {
    f(s);
}
}`

Comment: *The value of f()* ... hm, the value of a function call can be regarded as the value that is returned from the function. So if you have a function like `function f() {return 2;}` the value of `f()` would be `2`

Comment: This code looks like it has been run through a minimizer. You should try to find the unminified code if you're learning. It's very hard to work out what code does when all variables are renamed to single characters

Comment: Thank you for your answer,

but may i ask another question?

in this function,

function addElementEvent(o,e,f){
  var of = o[e];
  var f2 = function(){of();f();}
  o[e] = !is_function(of) ? f : f2;
 }

There is a LOC

  o[e] = !is_function(of) ? f : f2;


does this LOC means

if is_function is not equal to var of (which has a value of o[e]) return f
else return f2?

Comment: It looks like "registering" of a function.
1st line: get old ristered function - 
2nd : build a function, which calls the old and the new registered function - 
3rd : if there was an old registered function install the function of line 2, otherwise only the new one.

Comment: Hi holder? May I ask is your comment pertaining to this function?
 function addElementEvent(o,e,f){
  var of = o[e];
  var f2 = function(){of();f();}
  o[e] = !is_function(of) ? f : f2;
 }//addElementEvent
or the second one which is _loadIamage
thank you

Comment: to the first one `addElementEvent`

Comment: Thank you very much, seems I got it already.
Thanks for answering my question

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering what is the value of f().

The return value of calling `f` depends on what `f` is.

`f` is the third argument to the function.

Since you haven't shown us how the function is called, we can't tell you what `f` does.

> Is that line a shortcut for an if,else statement?

No. It is a function expression that includes an if statement. There's no else in it at all.

```
var i_onload = function(){
    _loadImage[s] = true;
    if(f) { 
      f(s);
    }
};
```

Comment: I actually got the code in this link http://www.devtrix.net/sliderman/download.html, with a filename demo2.
I hope you don't mind but may you please check the code since i want to show you how the function is called but don't know how. Thank you!